# Данные в загруженном файле не меняются

Tags: c++

Я недавно начал заниматься C++, и пишу простую программку которая получает данные из файла который находится в интернете.
Сама функция:

```
string GetStringFromUrl(LPWSTR url, LPWSTR path)
{
    string result;
    HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, url, path, 0, NULL );
    inFile.open(path);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        throw std::exception("CANT_OPEN_FILE");
    }
    //get text
    inFile >> result;
    inFile.close();
    return result;
}
```

При помощи неё я пытаюсь получить данные из файла находящемуся по адресу к примеру: http://example.com/test.php

Данные на целевой странице меняются (берутся из MySQL бд), и проблема в том что первый раз программа загрузила файл и выдала нужное значение (123 например), а после того как я в БД поменял значение программа упорно продолжает говорить что в файле всё-ещё 123, хотя значение уже поменялось. Если я зайду по целевому адресу то увижу что значение поменялось, но не смотря на это программа твердит что там остались старые данные.
(пробовал удалять файл под конец операции но результат тот-же).

Что я мог упустить?

+При этом когда я перезапускаю программу значение всё-же меняется.

Comment: вот наверное https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75432/how-can-i-prevent-urldownloadtofile-from-retrieving-from-the-cache

Comment: Можно программу целиком? хотя бы тот кусок, где ты пользуешь функцию.

Comment: @Nik , проблема решена. Она была из-за того что при повторной загрузки функция брала данные из кеша.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> вот наверное [stackoverflow.com/questions/75432/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75432/how-can-i-prevent-urldownloadtofile-from-retrieving-from-the-cache)
> – [Pavel Gridin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/241270/pavel-gridin)